# Django and Osgeo (closed)

Tags: osgeo, django

I want to use osgeo tools in a virtualenv with Django. I already followed the [directions in the Django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/) succesfully on different linux systems. But this time I got stuck while intalling GDAL.

My system is Lubuntu 15.10.

```
$ tar xzf gdal-1.9.2.tar.gz
$ cd gdal-1.9.2
$ ./configure
$ make
```

After a while 'make' hangs with this message:

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -DOGR_ENABLED -I/home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/port -I/usr/include -c json_object.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o ../../o/.libs/json_object.o
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:634:0,
                 from /home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/port/cpl_port.h:132,
                 from /home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/port/cpl_conv.h:34,
                 from json_object.c:12:
json_object.c:29:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
   char* strndup(const char* str, size_t n);
         ^
GNUmakefile:23: recipe for target '../../o/json_object.lo' failed
```

I could trace the problem back to this command

```
$ gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -DOGR_ENABLED -I/home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/port -c /home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson/jsonc/json_object.c
```

which results in:

```
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:634:0,
              from /home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/port/cpl_port.h:132,
              from /home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/port/cpl_conv.h:34,
              from /home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson/jsonc/json_object.c:12:
/home/user/tmp/gdal-1.9.2/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson/jsonc/json_object.c:29:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’
char* strndup(const char* str, size_t n);
```

relevant lines in json_object.c are:

```
12 #include "cpl_conv.h"
13
14 #include "config.h"
15
16 #include <stdio.h>
17 #include <stdlib.h>
18 #include <stddef.h>
19 #include <string.h>
20
21 #include "debug.h"
22 #include "printbuf.h"
23 #include "linkhash.h"
24 #include "arraylist.h"
25 #include "json_object.h"
26 #include "json_object_private.h"
27
28 #if !HAVE_STRNDUP
29   char* strndup(const char* str, size_t n);
30 #endif /* !HAVE_STRNDUP */
```

---

I realize I am not working with the most recent version. It looks like Gdal-1.9.2 has a bug which caused my problem as commented by @huckfinn but finally I used the recent version Gdal-1.11.2 which does not cause any trouble. So problem is 'solved'

Comment: Should be present (..see http://linux.die.net/man/3/strndup) via `/usr/include/string.h` and linked against `glibc`. Do you work in such a GNU environment? What says `./configure` to the `strndup` availabilty (yesy/no)?

Comment: I also see that you have a `gdal-1.11.2` and a `gdal-1.9.2` version in your post. Do you mixed somthing up?

Comment: don't know sure what you mean with 'what says ./configure ..'. The output of .configure in gdal-1.9.2 does not contain the text 'strndup'. If you want me to post the output of ./configure or anything else let me know.

Comment: changed gdal-1.11.2 to gdal-1.9.2, was just a typo. (quite) sure i am not mixing up versions.

Comment: I agree `~/install.d/gdal-2.0.1$ ./configure | grep strndup` seems to be empty. In which operation system you try to build the library. This is important because, the function `strndup()` is a GNU extention not part of the C99 standard and not POSIX conform until version `200809L`. ..see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168371/3338646

Comment: I encounter the problem in ubuntu15.10. If I do the samen in ubuntu14.04 everything goes fine. Also in 14.04 "gdal-1.9.2 $./configure" the text 'strndup' is not available.

Comment: Sorry I've not  registered the Lubuntu 15.10 remark. I found this very old bugreport ..10 years ago `https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3655` ..may be the patch is lost in your distribution https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/attachment/ticket/3655/rhel4-geojson.patch ..have a look at your `config.h` and post a bug report to OSGEO if the patch lines are missed.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I checked 'gdal-1.9.2//ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson/jsonc/config.h'. It has the  'STRNDUP' lines conform in the url you posted.

Comment: So send a bug report to then OSGEO team..

Comment: oops. now I realize the version I am working in (1.9.2) is not the last version (1.11.2). In 1.11.2 config.h the 'STRNDUP' are not available. But if I remove those lines in 1.9.2 config.h the same problem continues to exist. Anyway I first have to check if my problem is solved in 1.11.2. I keep you posted.

Comment: we're waiting..